# Angular component value not reflecting in HTML

Tags: angular

I have predefined array in angular component.First I print the value on HTML. On button click am using splice to change the array value. The value is changed but it is not reflecting in HTML.

```
<h3>Array before</h3>
<br><br>
{{array}}
<br><br><br>
<button type="button" (click)="methodSplice();">click</button>
<br>
<h3>Array After</h3>

<label>array:</label>
{{array}}

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My Angular App';
array = [];
temp:any;
arr1:any
constructor(){

}
ngOnInit(){
  this.array = [1,2,3,4,5];
}
  methodSplice(){
    this.array.splice(2,4);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you need to assign the value back to `this.array` (or in other terms: update the existing value).

```js
  methodSplice(){
    this.array = this.array.splice(2,4);
  }
```

Your component file will look like this.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  array = [];
  arr1:any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.array = [1,2,3,4,5];
  }
  methodSplice(){
    this.array = this.array.splice(2,4);
  }

}
```

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qq1rkx) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is not changing because of original array is not change.
"The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s)."

I mean splice method creates a new array and returns it.

If you want to get result of splice method, directly assign it to the your original array.

```
 methodSplice(){
   this.array= this.array.splice(2,4);
  }
```

Or, If you want to get rest part after splice method do following:

```
 methodSplice(){
   this.array.splice(2,4);
   this.array= this.array.slice();
 }
```

Or, maybe you can use filter method:

```
 methodSplice(){
   this.array= this.array.filter((i,v)=> i<=2);
 }
```

```js
let array;
function resetTheArray(){ array = [1,2,3,4,5];}
resetTheArray();

console.log("Original array: " + array.toString());
array.splice(2,4);
//array=array.slice(); You need this to trigger your original array to say angular I am changed.
console.log("I am rest of splicing: "+ array.toString());

resetTheArray();
array=array.splice(2,4);
console.log("I am the removed part: "+ array.toString());

resetTheArray();
array = array.filter((i,v)=> i<=2); // you can add more conditions
console.log("I am the rest of filtering: "+ array.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Thought array will be automatically updated even though we didn't assign it.

Comment: @venkatesh, If you use this the array will contain the elements you wanted to remove, I'm guessing that's the opposite of what you wanted.

Comment: @venkatesh You are welcome. I see. splice method creates new array and returns it

Comment: @venkatesh please check the result!

Answer (score 1):

You have splice the array correctly, but you didn't assign it to the existing array. Do like this.

```
methodSplice(){
   this.array= this.array.splice(2,4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is not updated because angular change detection only works when you change the reference, and [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) works in place (without changing the reference to the array after manipulation).

Also, **don't do** this unless you want the array to contain the elements you removed:

```js
this.array = this.array.splice(2,4);
```

Because `splice()` returns the removed elements and I doubt that's what you want.

Instead, what you can do is force a shallow copy of the array by calling [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) like this:

```js
  methodSplice(){
    this.array.splice(2,4);
    this.array = this.array.slice();
  }
```

This will change the reference to the array and angular should pick up the changes and refresh your view (HTML).

Comment: This is exactly what i needed.